# How to block downgrade of a package using dpkg?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I want to prevent installation of lower version of the package over higher version using `dpkg`.

Answer (score 7):

`dpkg` has option `--refuse-downgrade` which will do just that.

(The apt tools have a different, more complex mechanism for managing version preferences, which resides in `/etc/apt/preferences` and `/etc/apt/preferences.d`.)